# SetConsoleWindowInfo not throwing error but crashing my C++ code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am playing around with C++ and the command prompt but when I try to set my console window size, the function doesn't give the desired result. But when I call `GetLastError()`, it doesn't return any error string. I am on Windows 11 and using Visual Studio 2022 with Visual C++. Here is my code...

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define SCREENX 120
#define SCREENY 60

int main()
{
  CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi = { sizeof(cfi) };
  cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
  cfi.nFont = 0;
  cfi.dwFontSize.X = 4;
  cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 4;
  cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
  cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;

  SMALL_RECT coords = {
      SCREENY,
      0,
      SCREENX,
      0
  };

  wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[SCREENX * SCREENY];
  HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | 
  GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
  DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;


  wcscpy_s(cfi.FaceName, L"Consolas");
  if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, false, &cfi))
      return 801;

  if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &coords))
      MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("" + GetLastError()), TEXT("ERROR"), MB_OK);
      return 802;

  SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
}
```

EDIT : while knowing why `GetLastError()` isn't functioning would be helpful, I more want to know why `SetConsoleWindowInfo()` isn't working.

Comment: Are you saying that `GetLastError` returns `0`?

Comment: Under the line `if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &coords))`, I believe that you have `{` `}` braces missing. If you want both statements to be executed, then you need braces. Otherwise, only one statement will be executed conditionally and the other one will be executed unconditionally.

Comment: `// This is inside of int main()` -- Why not simply have `int main() {` and then close this code with `}`, so that it is closer to a [mcve]?

Comment: *it fails to work* -- Please be more specific as to what this "failure" is.  Is it an access violation?

Comment: `MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("" + GetLastError()), TEXT("ERROR"), MB_OK);` -- You may be a "PythonWarrior", but C++ is not Python.  This is not how to turn an integer into a string in C++: `TEXT("" + GetLastError())` -- you are adding two pointers, not doing any string concatenation.  Do not use Python as a model in writing C++ code.  All you will accomplish is have 1) buggy programs, 2) Inefficient programs, and/or 3) Programs that look weird to a C++ programmer.  You accomplished 1) and 3) in that piece of code.

Comment: BTW, the `"" + GetLastError())` mistake is made by a ton of folks who use Java, Javascript, Python, or similar languages that have this weird-looking facility in turning a numeric value into a string, and believe C++ has the same thing also.  It is weird because a C++ programmer would never know to do that, let alone see anything like that, while it is common in those other languages.  The bad thing is that the code compiles, but does not do what you think it does.  To turn an integer into a string, there are several functions in C++ to do that, and doing a search would show how to do it.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel based on what is being executed, yes

Comment: @AndreasWenzel about the `if` statement, it should execute both because I ran the same code bit but instead of providing the values in the `COORD` structure I initialized the values in later lines.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am very aware that this is not Python. From what I read from the tooltip in Visual Studio, it should return a L"".

Comment: @PythonWarrior *From what I read from the tooltip in Visual Studio, it should return a L""* -- The tooltip is right.  You are returning a pointer to a string literal, whose starting address is `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`, and who knows what is that address.   If your goal was to concatenate the number to an empty string, that does not do it.  The main issue is that you cannot learn C++ by using tooltips.  C++ is one of the most complex languages out there -- again, the code compiled, giving the indication that it did the same thing you thought it would do in Python.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie does it return a pointer or is the function itself a pointer?

Comment: @RandomEngineer `GetLastError` returns an integer.  That integer is added to the address of `""`, giving an address that `TEXT` uses.  Instead of `GetLastError()`, put an integer there instead.  That is effectively what you are doing, i.e `TEXT("" + 1234);`, if GetLastError happened to return 1234.  Now print out what `TEXT("" + 1234)` gives you -- it won't be `1234`.

Comment: Ah. That explains it. From what I was reading I thought it was returning a `wsring`. Thanks @PaulMcKenzie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that the issue is with `GetLastError()`, the problem is that you introduced undefined behavior when you attempted to call `GetLastError()` when you called `MessageBox()`.

This line:

```
MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("" + GetLastError()), TEXT("ERROR"), MB_OK);
```

has an issue with this parameter to `MessageBox()`:

```
TEXT("" + GetLastError())
```

The issue is that `+` does **not** turn `GetLastError()` into a string.  What it does is add two pointer values, the pointer to the string literal `""`, and the value of `GetLastError())`.  What ends up is a pointer to, I don't know, you don't know, no one knows.  But whatever it is `MessageBox` ends up using it, causing undefined behavior.

I am assuming that your intention was to "stringize" the value of `GetLastError()`.  That is not how to do it in C++.

First, it is better to know whether your application is actually a Unicode or Multibyte (MBCS) application.  The reason is that the `TEXT` macro will be either a wide string or narrow string, depending on the application type (check your project settings).

Let's assume it is Unicode, and you're not using MBCS (the default setting for projects that use Visual Studio).  To turn a value into a string:

```
#include <string>
//...
if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &coords))
{
    std::wstring errMsg = std::to_string(GetLastError());
    MessageBox(NULL, errMsg.c_str(), L"ERROR", MB_OK);
    return 802;
}
```

If for some reason it is an MBCS project:

```
#include <string>
//...
if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &coords))
{
    std::string errMsg = std::to_string(GetLastError());
    MessageBox(NULL, errMsg.c_str(), "ERROR", MB_OK);
    return 802;
}
```